# Tensor product of two elements, one them is zero

Tags: tensor-products

Let V and W be two vector spaces over $\mathbb{R}$. I've see this property somewhere  but I'm not sure how to prove it.

Let  $ x \in V $ and $y \in W$, such that $x=0 $ or $y=0, $
then $x \otimes y = 0 \in V \otimes W$.

Help please!

Comment: Without loss of generality say $x=0$. Then we can write $x \otimes y = 0 \otimes y = (0+0) \otimes y = 0 \otimes y + 0 \otimes y$ because of the bilinearity of the tensor product. Then we can subtract $0 \otimes y$ on both sides to get $x \otimes y = 0 \otimes y = 0$. Works the same way with $y=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition of the [tensor product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product#The_definition_of_the_abstract_tensor_product), for any scalar $c \in \mathbb{R}$ and any vectors $x\in V$ and $y\in W$ we have

$$
(cx) \otimes y = x \otimes (cy) = c(x \otimes y).
$$

Suppose $x = 0$, then for any vector $z\in V$ we can write $x = 0 \cdot z$ , so

$$
0 \otimes y = (0\cdot z) \otimes y = 0 \cdot (z \otimes y) = 0 \in V\otimes W
$$

and similarly when $y=0$.